# Mapping type->type, similar to string->type via keyof

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, I can define the following type:

```
interface FooNameMapping {
    Bar: {bar: string};
    Baz: {baz: number};
}
```

the keys and mapped types I can then use in a signature:

```
function mapped<K extends keyof FooNameMapping>(arg: K): FooNameMapping[K] {
    return '' as any;
}
```

and call as follows:

```
let x = mapped('Bar'); //typed as {bar: string}
```

[link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20FooNameMapping%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Bar%3A%20%7Bbar%3A%20string%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Baz%3A%20%7Bbaz%3A%20number%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20mapped%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20FooNameMapping%3E%28arg%3A%20K%29%3A%20FooNameMapping%5BK%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20''%20as%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20x%20%3D%20mapped%28'Bar'%29%3B%20%2F%2Ftyped%20as%20%7Bbar%3A%20string%7D)

However, this is only good for types mapped from a string argument. Is there any way I can do something similar for a type mapped from another type?

In other words, I have the following overloads:

```
interface EnumeratorConstructor {
    new(col: Excel.Actions): Enumerator<Excel.Action>;
    new(col: Excel.AddIns | Excel.AddIns2): Enumerator<Excel.AddIn>;
    new(col: Excel.AllowEditRanges): Enumerator<Excel.AllowEditRange>;
    new(col: Excel.Areas | Excel.Ranges | Excel.Range): Enumerator<Excel.Range>;
    new(col: Excel.Borders): Enumerator<Excel.Border>;
}
```

Can I create a type somehow that will map from `Excel.Actions` to `Excel.Action`, and use that type in a single overload?

Comment: Not sure i follow what you mean when you say "create a type somehow that will map from Excel.Actions to Excel.Action" What member would this type have?

Comment: I think he means something like Haskell's type families, where `DesiredType` is "function" from type to type (`DesiredType<T> = ...`/type constructor `DesiredType: * -> *`), and `DesiredType<Actions> = Action`, `DesiredType<AddIns | AddIns2> = AddIn`, `DesiredType<any> = // error` (or `never`, or `any`), etc., just like how `K` in `mapped` maps from strings to types, in a roundabout sort of way. I highly doubt something like this, from the deep end of type-level programming, has an equivalent in TS.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir What I mean is, as HTNW says in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184285/mapping-type-type-similar-to-string-type-via-keyof#comment79337677_46184285) comment, that I am looking to specify the relatiionship between two types which can then be used in a function signature for the parameter type and the return type, much like `K extends keyof` uses the relationship between particular strings (as keys of `FooNameMapping`) to particular types (the types of `FooNameMapping`) to build overloads that use the given string as a parameter and return the related type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is currently no non-hacky way to do this and get automatic inference to work properly.  TypeScript currently lacks [type-level functions or type families](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families), which is what you'd need to implement this directly.  TypeScript has a `typeof` operator which, if [extended](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6606) to work for arbitrary expressions, especially [function application](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/17961), would serve your purpose.

What you can do right now is to make a type like this:

```
interface Example {
    a: {from: string, to: number};
    b: {from: number, to: string};
}
declare function typeMapping<K extends keyof Example>(x: Example[K]['from']): Example[K]['to'];
```

But the problem is that `K` will not automatically infer to `'a'` or `'b'`, but will always be just `'a'|'b'` unless you specify it explicitly:

```
let str: string;   
str = typeMapping(123); // error, return value is string|number
str = typeMapping<'b'>(123); // okay, but need to specify 'b'
str = typeMapping<'a'>(123); // error, 1 is not a string
```

But that's considerably worse than just using function overloads.

---

The hacky way to do it would be to use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to augment the type of the things you're using as input to the function, and explicitly give them a phantom property of the output type.  For example:

```
import * as Excel from 'excel'; // guessing at location

// add phantom property
declare module 'excel' {
  interface Actions {
    __outputType: Excel.Action
  }
  interface AddIns {
    __outputType: Excel.AddIn
  }
  interface AddIns2 {
    __outputType: Excel.AddIn
  }
  interface AllowEditRanges {
    __outputType: Excel.AllowEditRange
  }
  // ... etc
}

type Inputs = Excel.Actions | Excel.AddIns | Excel.AddIns2 | Excel.AllowEditRanges // ...

// here's the function now    
declare function constructEnumerator<I extends Inputs>(i: I): Enumerator<I['__outputType']>; 

declare let actions: Excel.Actions;
const ret = constructEnumerator(actions); // returns Enumerator<Excel.Action> as desired
```

This all works as far as it goes, but you might find yourself with TypeScript complaining that `__outputType` is missing on object literals you use to create any of those input types, so you'd need to deal with that (e.g., `as Excel.Actions` after the literal).  Is it worth it?

---

So, how desperately do you need this?  Can you deal with overloads or less-specific types until and unless type-level functions appear in TypeScript?  Or is the module augmentation hack the way to go?  It's up to you, I guess.

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In this case, these objects are never created via object literal, but always using the `new ActiveXObject` factory function, or methods of other such objects; so I could use a phantom property. However, I don't think I'll use this; it feels too "hacky".

Comment: Could this be implemented using the new [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) in Typescript 2.8?

Comment: Yes.  You could now hardcode your list as something like: `type Enumerator<I> = I extends Excel.Actions ? Excel.Action : I extends Excel.Addins | Excel.Addins2 ? Excel.Addin : .... `.  There's probably also a way to use a generic `TypeMap<T, M>` where `T` is the input type and `M` is a mapping from input types to output types; not sure how important that is to you.